# One function for Mark ring

Tags: emacs, elisp

Apologies for the very unclear title.

Basically in emacs you can do C-SPC C-SPC to set a mark then C-u C-SPC to come back to that mark point.
How is it possible to have a function that would set mark and go to the location (if mark was set previously using that function).

Meaning, I want to tie C-M-f2 to set a mark ( if one was not set ) so simulate C-SPC C-SPC and if a mark was set previously, C-M-f2 will go to that location simulating C-u C-SPC.

In C this will be something like:

```
bool mark = 0;
while (1) {
 if (mark) {
  command = C-u C-SPC;
  mark = 0;
 } else {
  command = C-SPC C-SPC;
  mark = 1;
 }
}
```

Comment: First, you should only have to press C-Space once to set the mark. Pressing C-Space a second time should deactivate the mark.

Second, I'm not sure I understand what you want. Do you simply want a single keybinding that will set the mark if it isn't set and jump to it if it is?

Comment: I'm really curious as to why you want this. All I can envisage is all the ways in which it could be really annoying :) I assume there's a specific use-case which is different from the usual set/pop mark uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think using the mark is the right solution for this, but here's something that uses a register instead.

```
(defun register-set-or-jump ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((pos (get-register :saved-pos)))
    (if (markerp pos)
        (progn
          ;; Saved position found.
          ;; Jump there and clear the register.
          (jump-to-register :saved-pos)
          (set-register :saved-pos nil)
          (message "Jumped to saved position"))
      ;; No saved position available.
      ;; Save point to the register.
      (point-to-register :saved-pos)
      (message "Saved position to register"))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-M-f2>") 'register-set-or-jump)
```

The reason I suggest using [a register](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Registers.html) rather than [the mark](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark.html) is that many Emacs commands rely on and/or modify the mark, whereas you can use a register more-or-less as you wish.

Comment: jbm, I have been using the function you implemented and it helped me a lot.
I was wondering, how is it possible to view a message on the prompt when setting the register and when using it.
I just need a message to say "register set" and another one "register used"...something like that.

Comment: You can use the [message](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/message.html) function to print a message to the echo area. I updated my answer to include messages. I'm glad it's been helpful - thanks for letting me know.